# If x,y,z is positive then find the minimum value of $x+y+z+\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} +\frac{1}{z}+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If x,y,z is positive then find the minimum value of **$x+y+z+\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} +\frac{1}{z}+1$**

I know this can be solved by the relation AM$\geq$GM$\geq$HM. But I do not how to apply here and proceed.

Please help me out. Thank You!

Comment: $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$ by AM-GM, and same for $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality, we know that $$x+y+z+\frac1 x+\frac 1 y+\frac 1 z\geq 6\sqrt[6]{xyz\frac{1}{xyz}}=6$$Thus, the minimum value of the expression is $6+1=7$ and the equality holds when $$x=y=z=\frac1 x=\frac1{y}=\frac{1}{z}$$which happens when $x=y=z=1$ as $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^+$

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to show that $x+\frac1x\ge2$. Since there are no dependencies between $x,y,z$, the minimum value of the given expression is $2+2+2+1=7$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply AM-GM inequality for $7$ numbers: $x,1/x,y,1/y,z,1/z, 1$ and you are done. See it?

Answer (score 0):

$x+y+z+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+1 \geq 6 \sqrt[6]{x \cdot y \cdot z \cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{z} } + 1=7$, where the equality is obtained in $x = y = z = \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{z} =1.$